# Поставил минус на вопрос или ответ, обоснуй его!

Tags: предложение, вопросы, ответы, оценка-ответа

Как Вы думаете, если автор вопроса или тот, кто ответил на вопрос, получает минус за свои действия, он имеет право увидеть обоснованность таких действий?

Насколько было бы удобней, когда хочешь поставить минус бал, появляться обязательное поле, где надо обосновать свою оценку! И автор вопроса или ответа может ознакомиться с данным решением и вполне возможно у него появится мотивация изменить что-то в лучшую сторону.

Сейчас никто не мешает, поставил минус, ну не понравилось мне, и пойти дальше, а ты думай, что он этим минусом тебе хотел сказать...

Надеюсь своим вопросом немного улучшить сервис, очень не хватает возможности увидеть, за что ставят минус.....

Comment: Ну будут там разную ерунду писать, поможет?

Comment: да тогда, можно обращаться к модераторам, что Ваш вопрос или ответ специально занижают, без обоснования и другие это то же видеть будут...

Comment: Я за безграмотность и косноязычие минусы не ставлю, но тут очень хотелось. Подправил ваш текст, а с первым предложением во втором абзаце разберитесь, пожалуйста, самостоятельно. По-русски так не говорят.

Comment: @ИндиПутный а почему должно быть обоснование? Не нравится - минусанул, пошел дальше. Давай тогда и плюсы обосновывать.

Answer (score 4):

В настоящее время сам движок so не поддерживает такого механизма (требовать обоснования минуса). И надо понимать, что движок русского so является типовым для всей сети, поэтому намного более полезно подымать обсуждение на англоязычной мете (там ближе к центру принятия решений по доработкам движка), вполне возможно, что подобная фича со временем будет реализована. Почему бы и нет? Я вижу, что подобное сделано на хабрахабре, там с недавних пор сделали выпадающий список причин при минусовании статей.

Что можно сделать уже сейчас?

Во-первых, неплохо бы понять, идёт ли массовое минусование или это один-два случайных минуса. Такое бывает, что даже неплохой ответ получает минус, а то и два. Это не обязательно свидетельствует о проблемах самого ответа, его качестве. Массовое же минусование действительно может свидетельствовать о серьёзных проблемах ответа.

Во-вторых, можно при первом минусе под ответом оставить комментарий "прошу пояснить за что ставите минусы -- постараюсь исправить", это позитивно скажется на восприятии вопроса. У нас ведь не особо злые люди, но ведь всем жаль тратить время на откровенно мусорные посты, поэтому хочется просто минусануть без пояснений и идти дальше. Обещая исправить вы ставите себя в категорию людей, которым "не всё равно" и на такое ответственное поведение обычно и отвечают соответствующим образом.

В-третьих, можно зайти в [основной](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) чат сообщества и спросить там, что не так. Киньте ссылку на конкретный вопрос, вполне вероятно что те, кто сейчас онлайн подскажут.

Comment: Полностью согласен! Но есть еще момент, минусы не только касаются моего ответа или вопроса, иногда видишь хороший вопрос|ответ другого пользователя, а у него минусы, и не совсем понятно, за что ? и что этим хотели сказать..