# "Эффект прохожего" - хорошо это или плохо при оценке вопроса/ответа?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

Я думаю, из заголовка многие догадались, о чём пойдет речь. Но тем не менее напишу, чтобы было понятно всем :)

Много раз видел ситуацию, не только на ruSo, но и на enSo, когда у вопроса или ответа начинают появляться минусы. Я бы мог выделить несколько причин появления негативной оценки:

- Вопрос/ответ реально плох (не отвечает на поставленный вопрос, кривое форматирование, недостаточно информации).
- Вопрос/ответ не понравился кому-либо, так как он/она сделал бы иначе и все было бы красивее (на результат довольно часто это не влияет), человек с первых строчек вопроса/ответа ставит минус не вчитываясь в детали.
- Может еще много других причин есть :)

Теперь ближе к эффекту указанному в заголовке. Это мое личное наименование, не знаю может где-то ещё встретится, поэтому просьба - не использовать как официальную терминологию. Возьмём самую обычную ситуацию: пришёл новый человек на so и задал вопрос. Человек не знает всех плюшек форматирования вопроса и прочего. Новый вопрос плох (недостаточно инфы и кривое форматирование), понятное дело, все, кто знает правила данного ресурса, начинают жёстко минусовать вопрос и голосовать за закрытие. Со стороны постоянного юзера - `"я молодец, я избавлю этот мир от зла"`. Со стороны ТС - `"нет ответов, проблема остается, никто ничем не помог, появились какие-то минусы, какое-то непонятное закрытие вопроса`".

В итоге: довольные старички сайта, они предотвратили появление плохого вопроса, новичок в замешательстве так как ему никто не помог. **Люди** приходят, смотрят вопрос, ставят минус, голосуют за закрытие и уходят - **проходили мимо** как прохожие :)

Лично мое мнение - **ставишь минус, напиши почему**. Объясните свою позицию, чтобы тот кому поставлен минус понял где натупил, ошибся, что не так и задумался над исправлением. Потому что лично мне кажется, что такими действиями мы конечно "избавляем мир от зла", но кроме хорошего есть и плохое - сайт потерял пользователя. Это потенциальный отвечающий и задающий вопросы - тот кто будет наполнять эту базу знаний.

Надеюсь услышать ваше мнение и извините за столь длинный пост :)

Comment: Связанные обсуждения: [раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9850/15479), [два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4013/15479), [три](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277/15479).

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, и да вопросы связанны с моим :) спасибо, но я так понимаю дальше инициативы дело не идет?)

Comment: Если вопрос про то, будут ли что-нибудь на уровне движка менять, то вряд ли. Единственное, что мы можем сделать как сообщество - это привить нашим участникам привычку пояснять свои минусы.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, это будет сложновато)) люди не любят когда их что-то заставляют делать или влияют на их действия, данный вопрос будет прочитан не всеми участниками сообщества, поэтому всем донести инфу не получится :)

Comment: А мне больше вот за такое обидно: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59792071/4928642

Comment: @Qwertiy, enSO это вообще другая история, там минусуют налево и направо, даже если вопрос написан практически идеально, все-равно никто ничего не отвечает и минуса летят стабильно :((

Comment: @Andrew, его ещё и закрывали. А я на его написание несколько часов потратил...

Comment: @Qwertiy, там эта проблема стоит еще острее чем здесь)) не знаю с чем это связано, но остается неприятный осадок после таких ситуаций

Comment: @Qwertiy предположу, что там надо было все же MCVE сделать (ударение на M), и вам в каментах пишут, что формулировка вопроса заточена под ответ, что тоже не есть хорошо. Так же, судя по сниппету, вопрос не в том "как наблюдать", а в том "как мне сделать хинт реагирующий на скролл". Ну и еще недостаток в том, что вы опасаетесь просадок по производительности, но не привели сколько-нибудь конкретных замеров. Так что читайте что вам пишут в комментариях (и на мете). Вобщем вам все разжевали.

Comment: "*ставишь минус, напиши почему*" - совершенно согласен. Правда, с вопросами есть исключение - если минус сопровождается голосованием за закрытие.

Comment: Считаю, что такой проблемы у нас просто нет. И вы, так как имеете 10k+, можете сами в этом убедиться, зайдя в [инструменты модератора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tools). Я мониторил информацию о самых заминусованных вопросах последние дни и не увидел того, о чём Вы говорите. Поддерживаю Эникейщика. Зато увидел, что предлагается и принимается довольно большое количество правок. Так что всё у нас пока хорошо, на мой взгляд.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Проблема преувеличена. Именно "жёстко" минусуют вопросы только одного типа: "написать код, чтобы он считал Х/У, на питоне/с/яве, желательно объяснить каждую строчку как для тупых, зачёт в понедельник". Тратить в этих случаях время на комментарий - бесполезно и много чести. Все остальные плохие вопросы получают один, максимум два, минуса, а порой и один-два ответа. Комментировать здесь минус? Обычно это ни к чему ни приводит, так что зачем стараться.

Comment: Согласен, очень часто новоприходцы «лезут в воду, не зная броду», то есть сразу, не глядя, не ознакомившись с правилами сообщества в лоб задают свой вопрос, не удосужась прочитать хотя бы основные положения о том, как себя вести и как лучше задать свой вопрос. На большинстве форумов и досок объявлений такое жестко закреплено в разделах, и новоприбывшие по крайней мере должны прочитать это чтобы не попасть «под раздачу». Я понимаю что у него/неё «горит» и нужно достичь результата, но всё-таки нужно хотя бы немного освоиться в новой среде.

Answer (score 5):

Когда задаёшь вопрос, всё достаточно чётко описано, как он должен быть сформулирован и что из себя представлять.

Если вопрос этому не соответствует, то это уже проблема задающего вопрос, что его минуснули, в силу его интеллектуального развития. И комментарии тут абсолютно ни к чему. Нужно быть самому в состояний проанализировать свои ошибки.
Только по этой причине я видел минуса.

Опиши, какой хочешь получить ответ, и задай свой вопрос. И тебе всегда ответят, если найдутся знающие. Также соглашусь с комментатором выше, что SO — это не площадка по обучению каждой строчке кода и не решалка вузовских задач.

Comment: "Только по этой причине я видел минуса." - Вы видели только такие, но есть и множество других. Например периодически по ruSO пробегает тайный минусатор, который просто минусует всё подряд. Это видно, потому что группа вопросов (и все ответы к ним) почти одновременно отхватывают по минусу. Это, конечно, чья-то вредность, но я к тому, что минуса не только по указанной вами причине встречаются (и это не исключение - такое происходит регулярно). И я не единственный, кто такое замечал, как минимум @Harry, скорее всего, со мной согласится.

Answer (score 3):

С одной стороны, да, тезис совершенно правильный - объект должен быть оценен по его достоинству, а не по тому что о нем думают другие. Ваши голоса за вопросы и ответы должны зависеть только от вашей личной оценки.

Казалось бы, давайте все плюсы и минусы попрячем, пускай без них всё будет.

Но тогда как нам отделить хорошее от плохого? У оценок есть важная роль - показывать, "что такое хорошо, и что такое плохо". Причем не бинарно, а в градациях. Видя заминусованный вопрос, если вам интересно, вы его откроете и действительно убедитесь, что он *настолько* плох и заслуживает порицания. Или - хороший вопрос, покажет вам, что такое *действительно* хорошая формулировка, важная тема, и т.д.

Обратите внимание, что вы хотите спасти от "прохожих" только некую специфическую часть вопросов - "с минусами", и только от специфических "прохожих" - от "минусаторов".

Какие тут могут быть идеи? Может быть, не показывать вопросы с минусами с топе, или скрывать число минусов? Не знаю. Мне кажется проблема "прхожего" не настолько существенна. Тем более, что каждый прохожий может влепить не только минус, но и дать комментарий и совет.

*P.S. Про обязательные обоснования минусов, уже не раз были обсуждения, чего-то нового тут сложно придумать. Да и вопрос вы задали не об этом же?*

Comment: основной меседж моего вопроса - это попросить людей выражать свое мнение не только при помощи баллов но и комментарием)

Answer (score -6):

Обычно отношусь к минусаторам как к негативщикам и хамам. Тоже хотел бы, чтобы минус обязательно сопровождался обоснованием. На SO с такими изредка сталкиваюсь, логика неясна.

Например, десять человек поставили плюс, но одиннадцатый поставил минус. Что не понравилось? Не осилил? Не смог сделать свою задачу? Захотел поднять свой ответ, понизив чужие? Не смог решить - пройди мимо, посмотри другие решения, но нет, надо обязательно "впаять" минус. У одного экземпляра "подгорали булки", по всему топику минусы поставил.

Или задаёшь вопрос (по правилам). Но найдётся тот, кто подумает, что вопрос субъективен, где-то уже решён или очевиден. А для меня он не очевиден.

Встречался наглый экземпляр, которому не понравилось, что в ответе нет кода, а есть только слова и ссылки. Поставил минус и попросил модератора его удалить. Код писать было бесполезно - там текста больше, чем влезает в ответ.

Также был один клоун, который скопировал (перевёл) моё решение на Java и поставил мне же минус. После разборок обиделся и поставил ещё десять минусов в других топиках. Пришлось пообщаться с модераторами, минусы отменили, а свой ответ он удалил сам.

Человек тратил время, решал, может, его решение тоже кому-то поможет, зачем обязательно минусовать? Ну ладно там реклама или ругательства, но решение-то чем виновато?