# Отслеживание плохих ответов

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, удаление-ответов

*Во-первых*. Если вы минусуете ответ, будет ли он отслеживаться?

---

*Во-вторых*. Если «да», то этот вопрос не имеет смысла. Если «нет», то может возникнуть вот такая ситуация:

- Человек A пишет ответ с ошибкой (достаточно серьёзной, но исправимой) (не нарочно)
- Человек Б ставит минус (раз там ошибка) и пишет комментарий по поводу ошибки
- Человек В видит комментарий, соглашается, и ставит минус ответу и плюс комментарию
- Человек А видит комментарий, исправляет ошибку и пишет об этом человеку Б
- Человек Б видит, что ответ был исправлен, и снимает свой минус
- Человек В не знает о том, что ответ исправлен, и минус так и остаётся

Как вы *считаете*, является ли эта ситуация недостатком SO? Если «нет», то почему? Если «да», то как вы *считаете*, стоит ли при минусовании добавить подсказку: «Если ответ исправимый, отслеживайте его: скорее всего, автор данного ответа его исправит, и Вам об этом придёт оповещение, и вы получите свою реп. обратно» (последняя часть для особо пытливых); или добавить неявно минусованный ответ в отслеживание, а по истечению определённого времени его оттуда убирать (чтобы у сторожил SO не было 100500 минусованных ответов в отслеживании столетней давности)?

Единственное решение этой проблемы (на данный момент) – пересоздание ответа; но это работает в обе стороны, т. е. сбрасываются и плюсы, выставленные на ответе, а также данные ответы видят пользователи с 10 000+ реп., да и походит всё это на какой-то костыль.

Comment: Для большого SO это не проблема, так как в долгосрочной перспективе ответ получит то что заслужил. А ради нашего ruSO никто такие фичи добавлять не будет

Comment: @АндрейNOP на долгосрочную перспективу рассчитывать не приходиться, т. к. лично у меня изменения реп. происходит только на новых ответах – старые никто не трогает.

Comment: @АндрейNOP опять «рыночек порешал»…

Comment: Всё просто. Ставишь минус - отпишись в комментах. [Заодно и причина будет видна](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9850/213987).

Comment: @return Перевалите за первые десять тысяч - ещё как будет со старых вопросов/ответов приходить.

Comment: @AK прочитайте внимательно пример – там именно про тех, кто минус поставил, а комментарий не написал

Comment: Читал-читал. Вот пусть В примет за привычку отписываться, как и Б.

Comment: @AK тогда если вопрос популярен, но там может набраться 15 плюсов под комментом Б, значит *каждый* из этим 15-и человек должен писать свой коммент?

Comment: @AK я сам долго думал, как бы создать удобное решение, но так ни к чему и не пришёл(

Comment: Три комментария - это норм, а больше минусов бывает редко и у таких вопросов, которые прямо говоря пахнут так, будто их уже никак не отмыть редактированием.

Comment: @AK всё равно это решение мне не очень нравиться: гораздо *удобнее* поставить «+» под комментом, чем писать свой в духе: «согласен с XXX – ставлю минус». пожалуй, что единственное более или менее решение, которое мне до публикации  этого вопроса пришло в голову(

Comment: Возможно. Я просто реалист и вижу сколько фич было добавлено и каких в движок за последние три года. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @AK опять же, «рыночек порешал» – при капитализме частная монополия (Stack Exchange) – это зло (метафорическое), которое тормозит прогресс :( фичи бы вводились, если был бы конкурент, да и кому в голову придёт бодаться с таким гигантом, как Stack Exchange.

Comment: @AK кстати, пользуясь возможностью, можно задать вам вопрос: почему на старых вопросах до сих пор висят закладки??? ведь закладки это: решил запомнить вопрос, нашел ответ, удалил из закладок. или я что-то путаю? и зачем тогда отслеживание, если есть закладки?

Comment: @return, а может подойти к вопросу более радикально и вообще отменить репу (как минусы, так и плюсы)?

Comment: Согласен с ТСом насчёт недостатка SO. Самое простое решение, на мой взгляд, ставишь минус - оставляй комментарий, если комментарий уже есть - плюс комментарию и кнопка "отслеживать". Тем более после 15 минут (вроде бы) уже голос нельзя изменить, пока ответ не отредактируют. А вообще имеет смысл отслеживать любой пост, на который ставишь какой-либо голос, потому что после изменения может оказаться и обратное - автор ухудшил пост, а ты уже поставил плюс и не заметил новой редакции.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Несколько цинично. Но, в общем случае (!), мне как голосующему, нет смысла тратить время на "переоценку".

Так сложилось, что в момент времени N, ответ, по моей субъективной оценке, заслуживал минуса. Если автор ответа его поправит - отлично, это положительно сказывается на качестве информации, и другие пользователи\автор вопроса это оценят (как минимум, на статистически значимой выборке таких случаев).

Единственная ситуация, при которой я целенаправленно уберу минус - это если вопрос\ответ действительно привлек мое внимание. В таком случае пост окажется у меня в закладках, в отслеживаемых, и\или с моим комментарием. Для меня, это не действие по умолчанию (особенно не в модерируемых мной сообществах).

Во всех других случаях, **специально** отслеживать кто и что отредактировал я не считаю необходимым, и, подобные подсказки считал бы навязчивыми. Разумеется, **случайно** я могу вновь наткнуться на отредактированный пост и, разумеется, переголосую.

Исходя из этого, по моему мнению, предлагаемый функционал не стоит реализовывать.

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно. Если вопрос был исправлен, то он вновь попадет в начало списка вопросов и получает шанс, что минусовавшие опять в него заглянут (такое бывает). Сочтут нужным - исправят -1 на 0, а то и на +1.